# Are there contravariant monads?

Tags: haskell, monads, category-theory

Functors can be covariant and contravariant. Can this covariant/contravariant duality also be applied to monads?

Something like:

```
class Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b    

class ContraMonad m where
  return :: a -> m a
  contrabind :: m a -> (b -> m a) -> m b
```

Does `ContraMonad` class make sense? Any examples?

Comment: `contrabind` is a transformation from the next value you have not seen yet to the previous value. It doesn't make sense - I wonder if it can be used for building reverse sequences where your data in the origin is manipulated based on what you later passed to it - but in a purely functional language it'd make no way to extract it unless it's also a monad. Interesting question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, of course, it's possible to define it, but I doubt it would be of any use.

There is a popular saying that "monad is just a monoid in a category of endofunctors". What it means is, first of all, that we have a category of endofunctors (meaning, (covariant) functors from some category to itself), and what's more, we have some multiplication on this endofunctors (in this case — composition). And then monad fits into some general framework that we don't have to worry about right now. The point is, there is no "multiplication" of contravariant functors. Composition of two covariant functors is again a covariant functor; but composition of two contravariant functors is not a contravariant functor (rather it's a covariant functor, so, a totally different beast).

So, "contravariant monads" do not really make sense.

Comment: Good point about the composition of two contravariants being covariant.

Comment: The correspondence sending a category to its category of presheaves is a monad, and it is contravariant (this is not 100% accurate, but it can be made accurate). I believe presheaves are pretty useful :-)

Answer (score 18):

A contravariant functor is a functor from one category into its [opposite category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_category), i.e. from one category into another (albeit closely related) one. OTOH, a monad is foremostly an *endofunctor* i.e. from one category into *itself*. So it can't be contravariant.

This kind of stuff always tends to be a lot clearer when you consider the “fundamental mathematical” definition of monads:

```
class Functor m => Monad m where
  pure :: a -> m a
  join :: m (m a) -> m a
```

As you see there aren't really any arrows in there that you could turn around in the result, like you did with `contrabind`. Of course there is

```
class Functor n => Comonad n where
  extract :: n a -> a
  duplicate :: n a -> n (n a)
```

but comonads are still covariant functors.

Unlike monads, applicatives ([monoidal functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_functor)) needn't be endofunctors, so I believe these *can* be turned around. Let's start from the “fundamental” definition:

```
class Functor f => Monoidal f where
  pureUnit :: () -> f ()
  fzipWith :: ((a,b)->c) -> (f a, f b)->f c  -- I avoid currying to make it clear what the arrows are.
```

(exercise: define a derived `Applicative` instance in terms of this, and vice versa)

Turning it around

```
class Contravariant f => ContraApp f where
  pureDisunit :: f () -> ()
  fcontraunzip :: ((a,b)->c) -> f c->(f a, f b)
                            -- I'm not sure, maybe this should
                            -- be `f c -> Either (f a) (f b)` instead.
```

No idea how useful that would be. `pureDisunit` is certainly not useful, because its only implementation is always `const ()`.

Let's try writing the obvious instance:

```
newtype Opp a b = Opp { getOpp :: b -> a }

instance Contravariant (Opp a) where
  contramap f (Opp g) = Opp $ g . f

instance ContraApp (Opp a) where
  pureDisunit = const ()
  fcontraunzip z (Opp g)
     = (Opp $ \a -> ???, Opp $ \b -> ???) -- `z` needs both `a` and `b`, can't get it!
```

I don't think this is useful, though you might be able to define it with something like clever knot-tying recursion.

What might be more interesting is a *contravariant co-monoidal functor*, but this gets too weird for me right now.

Comment: Your Monad definition is not full. You must add `fmap :: (a -> b) -> (m a -> m b)`, which can be reversed.

Comment: No, `pure` and `join` are not enough. If not convinced, try to implement `bind` in terms of only `pure` and `join`.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov: sure, I forgot writing the `Functor` superclass.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov hmm true - sorry.

Comment: I believe ContraApp is Divisible, and it is very useful: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.3.3/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant-Divisible.html - but it's a little different to what you've got