# Skip the remaining actions in a monad - like return

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Hi I'm looking for a good way to allow a monad stack to skip the remaining actions, without skipping out entirely. Kind of like `return` in C-family langauges.

For example, let's say I'm using monadic actions for the side effects

```
type MyMonad = ??
doStuff :: MyMonad ()
doStuff = do
   r <- doSomething

   -- equivalent to if (r == "X") return; in C
   dontGoPastHereIf (r == "X")

   doSomeSideEffects r
```

So I want it to only perform `doSomeSideEffects` on some condition.

I know you can do something close to this with `guard` and `when` already. Is it possible to do without nesting though?

`ExceptT` already allows you to exit the normal flow and return with an early result. But with `ExceptT` the error / skip will propogate. I want to only skip the rest of the steps in the local function

```
doTwoSteps :: MyMonad ()
doTwoSteps = do
  -- if I used ExceptT, an error in the first function will skip the second.
  -- But I still want to do the second step here
  doStuff
  doStuff
```

It seems like bind `>>=` already does this. At least it's certainly within the possibilities of a monad, but I'm not sure how to do with monad transformers.

---

Here's a more complete example. This system is supposed to perform a "workflow". Each step can result in a response, which is supposed to stop the entire workflow and respond (`ExceptT`).

The workflow can be restarted by passing `ApplicationState`. If a step has a previous `Continue` we can skip the logic for that step, but we still need to execute the next step.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there some monad transformer or a way to define my `Flow` monad such that I can run `checkShouldSkip` without passing in an action?

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.Except (throwError, ExceptT)
import Control.Monad.State (gets, StateT, modify)
import Data.Text (Text)

data ApplicationState = ApplicationState
    { step1Result :: Maybe StepResult
    , step2Result :: Maybe StepResult
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

data StepResult
    = Stop
    | Continue
    deriving (Show, Eq)

type Flow a = StateT ApplicationState (ExceptT Text IO) a


flow :: Flow ()
flow = do
    step1
    step2

step1 :: Flow ()
step1 = do
    ms <- gets step1Result
    checkShouldSkip ms $ do
      info <- getStuffFromAServer
      let r = runSomeLogic info
      modify $ setStep1 $ Just r
      checkShouldRespond r

  where
    getStuffFromAServer = undefined
    runSomeLogic _ = undefined
    setStep1 r s = s { step1Result = r }


step2 :: Flow ()
step2 = do
    ms <- gets step2Result
    checkShouldSkip ms $ do
      -- this will run some different logic, eventually resulting in a step result
      r <- getStuffAndRunLogic
      modify $ setStep2 $ Just r
      checkShouldRespond r

  where
    getStuffAndRunLogic = undefined
    setStep2 r s = s { step2Result = r }


checkShouldSkip :: Maybe StepResult -> Flow () -> Flow ()
checkShouldSkip (Just Continue) _ = pure () -- skip the logic, continue
checkShouldSkip (Just Stop) _ = respond "Stop" -- skip the logic, stop everything
checkShouldSkip Nothing a = a -- run the action


checkShouldRespond :: StepResult -> Flow ()
checkShouldRespond Continue = pure ()
checkShouldRespond Stop = respond "Stop" -- if a response, stop all execution


-- rename because these aren't really errors, I just want to stop everything
respond :: Text -> Flow ()
respond t = throwError t
```

Comment: You may be looking for continuation monads `Cont` and `ContT`.

Comment: It looks to me like what you're asking for would break referential transparency - in `doTwoSteps` if you replace each `doStuff` with its definition, you've changed the behaviour.

Comment: @Alec any chance you could show me how to use ContT in my extended example?

Comment: @DavidFletcher Maybe, I'm doing the actions for the side effects. Also, in the real example the steps are different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with `ExceptT` if you’re willing to wrap the scope from which you want to be able to exit:

```
type EarlyReturnT m a = ExceptT a m a

withEarlyReturn :: (Functor m) => EarlyReturnT m a -> m a
withEarlyReturn = fmap (either id id) . runExceptT

earlyReturn :: (Applicative m) => a -> EarlyReturnT m a
earlyReturn = ExceptT . pure . Left
```

For example:

```
doStuff :: Bool -> IO String
doStuff x = withEarlyReturn $ do
  lift $ putStrLn "hello"
  when x $ earlyReturn "beans"
  lift $ putStrLn "goodbye"
  return "eggs"

> doStuff False
hello
goodbye
"eggs"

> doStuff True
hello
"beans"
```

Or with `ContT`, where the “early return” is a continuation.

```
type EarlyReturnT m a = ContT a m a

withEarlyReturn
  :: (Applicative m)
  => ((a -> EarlyReturnT m a) -> EarlyReturnT m a)
  -> m a
withEarlyReturn = flip runContT pure . callCC

doStuff :: Bool -> IO String
doStuff x = withEarlyReturn $ \ earlyReturn -> do
  lift $ putStrLn "hello"
  when x $ earlyReturn "beans"
  lift $ putStrLn "goodbye"
  return "eggs"
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. But then I run into the mtl restriction on having more than one ExceptT in the stack, right? There's no way to get this to work with my extended example?

Comment: @SeanClarkHess: Sorry, I don’t use `mtl`, so I’m not sure about workarounds, but maybe the `ContT` example I added will help.

Comment: @SeanClarkHess mtl does not place a restriction on having only one `ExceptT` in your stack. You can only "access" the top one with `MonadError`-polymorphic functions, but you're allowed to have as many as you want. I mention this in particular because it could be sensible to make your own newtype of `ExceptT` which exposes a `MonadEarlyExit` interface (which you invent and implement) but defers `MonadError` implementations to the underlying monad.

Comment: That is a great idea. I've never tried newtyping another transformer.

Answer (score 8):

The other answer is great! I wanted to talk a little bit about how exactly the continuation solution works so I wrote up this weird big thing. Hope it helps.

### Act I: A Trap Is Laid

We begin our journey in the low rolling plains of `IO`, our favorite state monad:

```
module Lib where

step1 :: IO String
step1 = do
  print "step1 - A"
  print "step1 - B"
  pure "--step1 result--"

step2 :: String -> IO String
step2 input = do
  print input
  print "step2 - A"
  print "step2 - B"
  pure "--step2 complete--"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- step1 >>= step2
  print "--done--"
  print result
```

We want to ascend upward and find a way of returning early from step one. Our first attempt is to introduce some sort of questionably-typed escape mechanism:

```
step1 :: (String -> ???) -> IO String
step1 escape = do
  print "step1 - A"
  escape "escaped!"
  print "step1 - B"
  pure "--step1 result--"
```

We cross our fingers, hoping that the string we pass to `escape` will end up as the string in `IO String`, and ponder what exactly can fill in those pesky question marks.

It seems to us that we need to hijack the `>>=` here if we are to have any hope of wresting the control flow away from the `IO` monad. We cautiously guess that we will need our own monad transformer.

```
newtype StrangeT inner a =
  StrangeT { runStrangeT :: a -> ??? }

lift :: IO a -> StrangeT IO a
lift io =
  StrangeT (\trapDoor -> io >>= trapDoor)

escape :: a -> StrangeT IO a
escape a =
  StrangeT (\trapDoorA -> trapDoorA a)

step1 :: StrangeT IO String
step1 = do
  lift (print "step1 - A")
  escape "escaped!"
  lift (print "step1 - B")
  pure "--step1 result--"
```

We can think of `trapDoorA` as an escape mechanism guarded by a key, the key being any value of type `a`. Once the door is open we fall through into the next step of the computation.

What type to insert for the question marks? We have sort of boxed ourselves into a corner; in order for this code to compile we it can only be:

```
newtype StrangeT inner a =
  StrangeT { runStrangeT :: (a -> inner a) -> inner a }
```

### Act II: Stranger Still

We now need to instance `Monad (StrangeT inner)`. Unfortunately we are going to run into a big problem. `StrangeT` is not a functor!

The reason for this is that "a" appears in the "negative position":

```
newtype StrangeT inner a =
  StrangeT { runStrangeT :: (a -> inner a) -> inner a }
                               -- ^^^^^^^
                               -- :(
```

(For a full discussion of this topic see [What is a contravariant functor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034077/what-is-a-contravariant-functor).)

We can employ a nasty trick, which is to split the "negatives" and the "positives" into two different type variables (`a` and `result`):

```
newtype StrangeT result inner a =
  StrangeT { runStrangeT :: (a -> inner result) -> inner result }

lift :: IO a -> StrangeT whatever IO a
lift io = StrangeT (\trapDoor -> io >>= trapDoor)

escape :: a -> StrangeT whatever IO a
escape x = StrangeT (\trapDoor -> trapDoor x)
```

This makes everything possible. We can now instance Functor, Applicative, and Monad. Rather than trying to puzzle out the answers though, we will simply let the type checker take over. Any answer that type checks will be the right one.

```
instance Functor (StrangeT result inner) where
  fmap a2b (StrangeT strange) =
    StrangeT $ \trapDoor -> strange (\a -> trapDoor (a2b a))
             -- ^^^^^^^^
             -- b -> inner result
```

Train of logic:

- `trapDoor` is the only way to build an `inner result` value.
- It needs a value of type `b`.
- We have `a2b :: a -> b` and `a :: a`.

  ```
  instance Applicative (StrangeT result inner) where
    pure :: a -> StrangeT result inner a
    pure a = StrangeT $ \trapDoor -> trapDoor a

    (<*>) :: StrangeT result inner (a -> b) ->
             StrangeT result inner a ->
             StrangeT result inner b
    (StrangeT strangeA2B) <*> (StrangeT strangeA) =
  --          ^^^^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^^
  --          (b -> inner result) -> inner result
  --                                    (a -> inner result) -> inner result
      StrangeT (\trapDoorB -> strangeA2B (\a2b -> strangeA (\a -> trapDoorB (a2b a))))
  --             ^^^^^^^^                 
  --             b -> inner result
  ```

Train of logic:

- We have `trapDoorB :: b -> inner result` (the *only* way to construct inner result), `a2b :: a -> b`, and `a :: a`.
- We need to construct a `StrangeT result inner b`;
- We therefore must at some point evaluate `trapDoorB (a2b a)`.

The monadic instance is about as difficult:

```
    instance Monad (StrangeT result inner) where
      (StrangeT strangeA) >>= a2strangeB =
         --     ^^^^^^^^
         --     (a -> inner result) -> inner result
        StrangeT
          (\trapDoorB -> strangeA (\a -> let StrangeT strangeB = a2strangeB a in strangeB (\b -> trapDoorB b)))
         -- ^^^^^^^^^                                 ^^^^^^^^
         -- b -> inner result                         (b -> inner result) -> inner result
```

There is only one way to construct `inner result`, which by falling through `trapDoorB`, so everything else is built toward that singular goal.

### Act III: A Fumble

We have defined a monad transformer without really knowing what it does or how it works! We simply smashed together the types that looked right.

It would behoove us then to see it in action:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  _ <- runStrangeT (step1 >>= step2) (\a -> pure a)
  print "--done--"
  print result
```

This results in the following output:

```
λ> main
"step1 - A"
"step1 - B"
"--step1 result--"
"step2 - A"
"step2 - B"
"--done--"
"--step2 result--"
```

How frustrating! We are right where we started from.

However, something peculiar happens if we define this function:

```
escape :: a -> StrangeT whatever IO a
escape x = StrangeT (\trapDoor -> trapDoor x)

escapeWeirdly :: a -> StrangeT whatever IO a
escapeWeirdly x = StrangeT (\trapDoor -> trapDoor x >> trapDoor x >> trapDoor x)

step1 :: StrangeT String IO String
step1 = do
  lift (print "step1 - A")
  escapeWeirdly "--step1 exit--"
  lift (print "step1 - B")
  pure "--step1 result--"
```

Output:

```
λ> main
"step1 - A"
"step1 - B"               <- trap door call #1
"--step1 result--"
"step2 - A"
"step2 - B"
"step1 - B"               <- trap door call #2
"--step1 result--"
"step2 - A"
"step2 - B"
"step1 - B"               <- trap door call #3
"--step1 result--"
"step2 - A"
"step2 - B"
"--done--"
"--step2 result--"
```

`step2` runs three times! It seems that "trapDoor" encodes some notion of "everything after this point in the control flow." Calling it once runs everything after it once. Calling it three times runs everything after it three times. Calling it zero times...

```
cut :: a -> StrangeT a IO a
cut x = StrangeT (\_ -> return x)

step1 :: (String -> StrangeT String IO String) -> StrangeT String IO String
step1 exit = do
  lift (print "step1 - A")
  cut "--step1 exit--"
  lift (print "step1 - B")
  pure "--step1 result--"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- runStrangeT (step1 undefined >>= step2) pure
  print "--done--"
  print result
```

Output:

```
λ> main
"step1 - A"
"--done--"
"--step1 exit--"
```

Nothing runs! This is *incredibly* close to what we need.

### Act IV: Success and the Price Thereof

What if we could mark a do-block of `StrangeT` actions as needing an early exit? Something very similar to our original escape mechanism:

```
step1 = withEscape $ \escape -> do
  lift (print "step1 - A")
  escape "--step1 exit--"
  lift (print "step1 - B")
  pure "--step1 result--"
```

What `withEscape` does is it runs the do-block as written until someone calls `escape`, at which point the rest of the computation is aborted *but* any computation outside the `withEscape` (namely Step Two here) runs as-is.

This helper must have a type of:

```
withEscape :: (??? -> StrangeT result inner a) -> StrangeT result inner a
```

Almost the exact same leap of faith we made when we went from `m a` to `(a -> m a) -> m a`.

Since we are passing a `String` to `escape` and binding the result of that computation to the next line of the do-block, we can now fill in those question marks:

```
withEscape :: ((a -> StrangeT result inner whatever) -> StrangeT result inner a)
              -> StrangeT result inner a
```

A tricksy type! We are going to have to navigate by type again to find the definition:

```
-- We have to call f at some point, and trapDoorA
-- is the only way to construct an inner result.
withEscape f =
  StrangeT (\trapDoorA -> let StrangeT strangeA = f ??? in strangeA trapDoorA)

-- f is passed the early exit value
withEscape f =
  StrangeT (\trapDoorA ->
    let StrangeT strangeA = f (\a -> ???) in strangeA trapDoorA)

-- We need to construct a StrangeT value
withEscape f =
  StrangeT (\trapDoorA ->
    let StrangeT strangeA = f (\a -> StrangeT (\trapDoorWhatever -> ???)) in
    strangeA trapDoorA)

-- We are going to *ignore* the trapDoorWhatever
-- we are supposed to fall into, and *instead*
-- fall through our original trapDoorA.
withEscape f =
  StrangeT (\trapDoorA ->
    let StrangeT strangeA = f (\a -> StrangeT (\_ -> trapDoor a)) in
    strangeA trapDoorA)
```

What happened here is that we stumbled onto a solution that gives us *two trap doors*. Instead of falling through the first door (which would make the helper boil down to something like `pure` in that it would resume normal control flow)  we chose to fall through the *original* door we built for ourselves. Fans of the movie *Primer* will recognize this as the original sin; normal people might just view all this with a confused look on their face.

Regardless, this **works**:

```
step1 :: StrangeT String IO String
step1 =
  withEscape $ \escape -> do
    lift (print "step1 - A")
    escape "--step1 exit--"
    lift (print "step1 - B")
    pure "--step1 result--"

step2 :: String -> StrangeT String IO String
step2 result = do
  lift (print result)
  lift (print "step2 - A")
  lift (print "step2 - B")
  pure "--step2 result--"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- runStrangeT (step1 >>= step2) pure
  print "--done--"
  print result
```

Output:

```
λ> main
"step1 - A"              <- early exit
"--step1 exit--"         <- step2 runs
"step2 - A"
"step2 - B"
"--done--"               <- back to main
"--step2 result--"
```

### Summary

- As telegraphed, this is the `ContT` monad and can be found packaged in the [transfomers package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html). What we have been calling trap doors are really continuations.
- `withEscape` is better known as `callCC` (call with current continuation); it lets you give the current continuation *at the time you called `callCC`* a name (`escape` in our examples); when you activate the continuation it allows you to return a value immediately.
- You can implement a great deal many things with continuations, including early returns and exceptions and generators and god knows what else. We have yet to even talk about delimited continuations (shift and reset). They represent something primal and fundamental to the structure of computer programming.
- For more information, see the series of papers linked from [Oleg Kiselyov's website](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/Computation.html). There is much much more to be said about continuations.

### Should you ever actually do this in real life?

Probably not. `ExceptT` tends to create fewer headaches in the long run.

### But is `ExceptT` cooler than `ContT`?

Hardly.

Comment: Did you miss Act IV?

Comment: This is great, thank you! Loved the Primer reference :)