# Apply, Applicative, Monad, etc for contravariant functors in cats?

Tags: scala, functor, scala-cats

I have the following trait...

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

trait Preference[-A] {
  self =>

  def compare(a1: A, a2: A): Int

  final def ordering[A1 <: A]: Ordering[A1] = {
    new Ordering[A1] {
      def compare(a1: A1, a2: A1): Int = {
        self.compare(a1, a2)
      }
    }
  }

}


object Preference {

  implicit val contravariant: Contravariant[Preference] = {
    new Contravariant[Preference] {
      def contramap[A, B](fa: Preference[A])(f: B => A): Preference[B] = {
        new Preference[B] {
          def compare(b1: B, b2: B): Int = {
            fa.compare(f(b1), f(b2))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to define `Apply`, `Applicative`, possibly even `Monad` instances for this trait but all of these type classes are extensions of `Functor`. Do versions of these type classes exist in Cats for contravariant functors?

Comment: I find that this infographic can often help with this kind of thing: https://github.com/tpolecat/cats-infographic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contravariant equivalent of `Applicative` in Haskell is [`Divisible`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.5/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant-Divisible.html), and `cats.ContravariantMonoidal` [allows to define both of its methods (`divide` is `contramap2`, `conquer` is `trivial`)](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/contravariantmonoidal.html). I am not immediately certain, though, if any `Divisible` has to be `Monoidal` in cats' sense.

For `Monad`, Kmett says

> [There is no contravariant Monad-like. You need C -> C, not C -> C^op. The twist denies you the ability to build nice structure.](https://twitter.com/kmett/status/432212549405118464)

Also [Are there contravariant monads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641500/are-there-contravariant-monads).

Comment: Any thoughts on a contravariant version of `Monad`?  Maybe I should take a look at what exists in Haskell and then try to find a cats' equivalent.

Comment: Added info on `Monad`.